# Cannot insert or update varchar empty/null value into always encrypted column

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

I am trying to update empty `""` or `null` value from C# using sql client into always encrypted column; however I am getting below error. It works if I pass a space `" "`.

Error:

> nvarchar(4000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db') is incompatible with nvarchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db')

Comment: Please post your code/query and the table schema. The error complains about the parameter/field size, not nulls or empty strings. One of them has a length of 50, the other 4000. How did you try to update the table? Did you use a parameterized query or stored procedure? What was the size of the parameter?

Comment: column schema is nVarchar(50)
If I pass any value it works, there is issue for empty and null values, 4000 size I have not used either in table or procedure, no idea from where it is taking 4000

Comment: If you don't use a size, a default one will be assumed. Post your code.

Comment: thank you, your reply helped, size is required while creating parameter object, that was missing in my code. working sample code below.

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@lastname", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            p.Value = string.Empty;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update associate set lastname=@lastname", connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(p);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

Comment: If you have solved the problem (I read your last comment that way?) please enter the solution as an answer and accept it. That removes the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code is below:

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@lastname", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        p.Value = string.Empty;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update associate set lastname=@lastname", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(p);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

The issue was the client parameter definition must match the encrypted column type on the server exactly.